# Archiving Gmail messages using Mutt: does simply deleting the message in mutt work?

Tags: gmail, mutt

*Question*: can someone confirm and/or explain the following observation?

---

After shopping for `~/.mutt/muttrc` settings over the web and digging into years-old (if not decades old) posts, I found the following mapping has an interesting side effect: **it seems to get the message ARCHIVED properly** for Gmail.

```
macro index,pager e  "<delete-message><sync-mailbox>"   "move message to trash"
```

Older posts suggested the following mapping, which all have noticeable side-effects as of creating new labels on my Gmail account in an unexpected fashion.

```
#macro index,pager e "<save-message>=[Gmail]/All Mail<enter><enter>" "Archive"
    # ==> Keeps creating new tags like [Gmail]/AllMail and [Gmail]/AllMailMail ...
#macro index,pager e "<save-message>=All Mail<enter><enter>" "Archive"
    # ==> Keeps creating new tags like `AllMailMail` and `AllMailMailMail` and 
    # so on, per each archive/push.
#macro index,pager A "<save-message>=Archive<enter>" "Archive Message"
    # ==> Well, Gmail is using "All Mails" tag/label to bin all emails for now. (Maybe I have also misread the original post from Ref #1).
```

### Reference

List of posts that I ran into:

1. [A note on archiving Gmail messages in Mutt](https://grantlucas.com/posts/2014/01/note-archiving-gmail-messages-mutt)
2. [Elegant mutt setup for use with gmail](https://www.rosipov.com/blog/elegant-mutt-setup-for-use-with-gmail/)
3. [Mutt, the Vim Way](https://ryanlue.com/posts/2017-05-21-mutt-the-vim-way) ==> I started to try out the `dd` mapping from this post, and was happy to discover that "deleting" in Mutt `==` "archiving" on Gmail (in Year 2019).

Comment: This depends on your setup. If you’re syncing messages with offlineimap/isync or use built-in imap there are surely differences. I believe I won’t be able to answer your question. But someone else could. Or try to ask on IRC #mutt or #neomutt on freenode and share your findings here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this behavior depends on how the messages are retrieved and also the settings in your email account;

answer from: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/11787139?hl=en

> I assume you are accessing your Gmail account from some e-mail client or app (as that's the only way deleted messages can be archived instead of deleted).
>
> - In the Gmail web interface, go to:  Settings->POP/IMAP
> - If you use POP3, go to:  POP Download->When messages are accessed with POP   (and select the appropriate option from the drop-down).
> - If you use IMAP, go to:  IMAP access->When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder   (and select
>     the appropriate option).